# I need to show a button press on a shape which is my background for my button

Tags: android, button, selector, shapes

This is my shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#80000000"
        android:endColor="#80FFFFFF"
        android:angle="45"/>
    <padding android:left="7dp"
        android:top="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:bottom="7dp" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

This is what I want for button pressed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#80FFFFFF"
        android:endColor="#80000000"
        android:angle="45"/>
    <padding android:left="7dp"
        android:top="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:bottom="7dp" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

I tried this code to link to the two shapes but when I set it as background it just made my button default gray.

and I added the selector to the background of my button, it has the right opacity as is but I need it to show a different colour (like white or something) when it is clicked.

anyone any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do it in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_bg_pressed"/>
   <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_bg_pressed"/>
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_bg_selected"/>
   <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

This is what i usually use for my theme

Comment: Thanks for this - what are btn_bg_pressed and btn_bg_selected?  are they pictures?

Comment: Thank you!  I just substituted it for my shapes and it works - well it works on the emulator and not my phone - but I suspect thats my phone :).